# Visual Studio for MAC Community has blurry font on dual display

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I installed Visual Studio for Mac Community
Version 8.1.4

But I have problem when I use dual monitor.
I have a retina MacBook Pro + Full HD monitor

Retina display:

[image]

Full HD monitor:

[image]

I tried to run this on my terminal.

```
defaults write -g CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled -bool NO
```

This command works but only on VS Code:

```
defaults write com.microsoft.VSCode.helper CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled -bool NO
```

Comment: The best place for getting some information on this would be to submit a report with all the appropriate information directly to the Visual Studio for Mac team here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/41/index.html

Comment: Indeed. I posted this issue on the official website: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/637072/visual-studio-for-mac-community-has-blurry-font-on.html

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but I have the same issue and found a solution for this: Just move (Window > Move .. ) the VS code from the retina display to the external monitor and then move back to the retina display.